# DataTables + PHP/AJAX - manipulate result before display

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I don't usually use `dataTables` via AJAX call but rather run SQL query and then pop the result into a table. For the sake of learning, I would like give dataTable + AJAX a try, but am a little confused as to how I best manipulate my result before displaying it in my table.

Following scenario:

I have a table with a list of users and display the users' avatar in the first column. The avatar image is saved in `assets/img/avatars/` and naming convention follows the users `id` number from the database (eg. `avatar_<user_id>.jpg`).

Before displaying the image though, I want to check if the image actually exists, and if not, use the default placeholder image (eg. `avatar_00.jpg`) instead.

Normally I would run my MySQL query and add a php `if` check to decide what images goes into the column. How do I do this with AJAX? Should I do my data manipulation directly in the javascript or in the `fetch_data.php` before the result array comes back?

My working sample code below:

EDIT:
long story short: how do I check whether an avatar image exists or not in AJAX and ensure that the placeholder is shown in DataTables where no file exists?

**HTML Table:**

```
<table id="global_address_book" name="global_address_book" class="table table-hover table-primary align-middle">
    <thead class="primary">
        <tr class="primary">
            <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Department</th>
            <th scope="col">Region</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#global_address_book').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "ajax": "fetch_data.php",
            "columns": [{
                    data: 'id',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        return '<div class="sidebar-comment-avatar"><a href="#"><img src="../../assets/img/misc/small/avatar/avatar-' + row.id + '.jpg"></a></div>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'first',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        return '<h5>' + row.first + ' ' + row.last + ' - ' + row.position + '<br><small><u>' + row.property + ' (' + row.property_code + ')</u> - ' + row.city + ', ' + row.country + '<br>Email: <a href="#">' + row.email + '</a> - Phone: ' + row.phone + '</small></h5>';

                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'department',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">' + row.department + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'region',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">' + row.region + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'region',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="#" style="font-size: 14px;">more details</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

fetch_data.php

```
<?php
// db settings
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'db_name';

// db connection
$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

// fetch records
$sql = "select id, first, last, phone, email, position, department, region, property_code, property, city, country from users2";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

$dataset = array(
    "echo" => 1,
    "totalrecords" => count($array),
    "totaldisplayrecords" => count($array),
    "data" => $array
);

echo json_encode($dataset);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If the returned data should only show images that exist, manipulate the data before returning it. If you want to check this using JS (which is much harder, as you have to request all images first to see which URLs throw a 404), do it there

Comment: "how do I check whether an avatar image exists or not in AJAX" - you don't. That's something you should do in PHP code on the server, not in JS code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to manipulate data directly in JavaScript.
You can return plain HTML in your PHP file, because DataTables will paste any content in the `<td>` element.

It's best to check if avatar exists before you send the response from your PHP file.
I'm assuming you have a DB with all the users. So check against that, and if no avatar file exists, place your placeholder HTML/Image instead

Comment: thank you, this makes perfect sense. Will have to break and manipulate the array in PHP before passing it on to DataTables then. Appreciate the help.